# social media login of my website not working in iphone

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-oauth

I'm using facebook and google plus login in my website and it is working fine at all devices except Iphone, I make a lot of searching I found that google has been block native apps from make authentication since 2017

update : the website I'm developing is a splash screen that opened to the user when he try to connect to cisco meraki access point to authenticate him and give him access to the internet ,
when an iphone mobile try to connect to the access point the splash screen opened in the native browser of it so the facebook and google plus buttons doesn't work

Do you have any suggestions or solutions about that issue?

Comment: Which one are you having problems in: A _web app_ or a _native app_ as you mention both in the question.

Comment: I added more details about the problem in the question

Answer (score 0):

I recently resolved this issue on a website I manage with these steps:

- login to console.developers.google.com,
- EDIT your APP, under;

  - Authorized JavaScript origins, and Authorized redirect URIs,
  - Enter:

    - http://yoursitenamehere.com
    - https://yoursitenamehere.com if it has ssl and
  - Save

Refresh your page and try to sign-in now.

For facebook:

- sign-in to your facebook developers platform

  - under facebook login
  - go to Settings
  - Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

    - (after filling your app domain details, Copy and Paste the code below Ctrl&Shift V) `https://example.com/?SuperSocializerAuth=Facebook` (replace the *example.com* with the domain name you're activating social login for)